# Create a batch file which synchronize two folders using text file validations

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want to create such scenarios in which there are two folders & subfolders of A and B, when there is an addition of files or data in folder A it should create the same files or data in folder B (including subfolder). Also, for example, there are 6 files in folder A and 7 files in folder B system automatically check the files and subfiles of folder A and B and delete the mismatched file(pqr.js
) from 'Folder B'. We also want to create a bridge or validator text file between folder A and B which validate the file names, for example if there is filename 'config.properties' which is present in text file (Validator) ABC.txt and that file is not present in folder A system should check the file name in validator before deleting any files from folder B. So if there are no such file name config.properties in folder A but present in validator text file system will keep that file in folder B though it is deleted from folder A.

[image]

```bat
set dirsrc=folder A
set dirdest=folder B
set validator=ABC.txt 

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo Source: "%dirsrc%"

echo Destination: "%dirdest%"

echo.

echo.

echo Cleaning files...

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:-d "%dirdest%"') do (

     set curdest=%%a

     set cursrc=!curdest:%dirdest%=%dirsrc%!

     if not exist !cursrc! (

     echo Deleting "!curdest!"

        del "!curdest!"

)

)

echo.

echo.

echo Cleaning directories...

set NLM=^

set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

rem Two lines left empty for NewLine to work

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:d "%dirdest%"') do (

     set curdest=%%a

     set cursrc=!curdest:%dirdest%=%dirsrc%!

     if not exist !cursrc! (

     set rmlist=!curdest!?!rmlist!

)

)

set rmlist=!rmlist:?=%NL%!

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("!rmlist!") do (

    if exist %%a (

    echo Removing directory "%%a"

    rmdir "%%a"

)

)

xcopy /i /y /e "%dirsrc%" "%dirdest%" /d
endlocal
```

All the scenarios are completed expect Validator scenarios.

Comment: Sound good to me! Please, do it...

Comment: Seems like you could do most of your requirements with ROBOCOPY.

Comment: yes squashman you are right, but read from file and exclude from deletion not supported by robocopy also. but thanks for suggestion.